# First & only cin is skipped, even after using cin.ignore

Tags: c++, input, cin, ros

**Edit 2:**

Well, turns out I was just being dumb! It wasn't anything to do with the code at all. I was running everything via a bash script, and because of how I was using it before (which also didn't require any input) I was still running it with & at the end - so obviously I couldn't get any input from that shell.

---

My program seemingly skips the line were I try to receive input using cin (it goes right to the next line).

**Edit: Please look at the bottom where I put the new code and what happens.**

I've searched here and googled, and I've found a lot of questions where people had the same problem! As far as I understand, the problem was almost always a leftover '\n' - but none of the solutions have worked for me sofar. This is the problematic code:

```
//char input_char;
std::string input_string;
//int input_int;

//std::string line; 

std::cout << "hello. your input: ";

std::cin.clear();
std::cin.ignore (std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n'); 

std::cin >> input_string;
// std::getline(std::cin, input_string);

std::cout << "input: " << input_int << endl;
```

I only need one character or number. I've tried it with a character, int, or string; and I've tried cin and getline. I've added clear and ignore as was suggested for other similar questions, but I still have the same problem.

This is at the beginning of my main, so I'm not doing any other cout or cin before this code. However, this is part of a larger project, and I'm using ros. Before the program gets to this part, there are other outputs which are handled through ros; no other input though.

I'd very much appreciate you help with this! I feel like I must be missing something really obvious...

**Edit: I've now commented out literally everything that isn't immediately related to this input**, and moved cin to the very top of the main. This is now the complete code (commented parts left out):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ros/ros.h>
#include <vector>
#include <ros/console.h>
#include "std_msgs/String.h"

//#include <SharedMessages/MicroconRequest.h>

/* ... */

//ros::Publisher reqPublisher;
//SharedMessages::MicroconRequest reqMsg;


/* ... */

int main( int argc, char* argv[] )
{

    char input_test;
    std::cout << "character: ";
    std::cin >> input_test;
    std::cout << input_test;
    std::cout << "did that work?";

    // Handle ROS communication
    ros::init( argc, argv, "Gestures" );
    ros::NodeHandle n;

    //ros::Subscriber joy_sub_ = n.subscribe<sensor_msgs::Joy>("joy", 10, joyCallback, this);
    //reqPublisher = n.advertise<SharedMessages::MicroconRequest>("MicroconRequest", 10);

    ros::Rate loop_rate(10);

    // Infinite control loop
    while (ros::ok())
    {

        /* ... */

        cntLoop++;

        ros::spinOnce();
        loop_rate.sleep();
    }

  // turn off microcontroller
  return 0;
}
```

Now what happens is the following:

```
$ ./startDemo.bash

Starting Minimal Example

$ character: a                # now I have time to input something, but...
a: Befehl nicht gefunden.     # = command not found]
                              # then it doesn't do anything, so I stop it
$ ./stopDemo.bash   
killing /Gestures

did that work?[ WARN] [1473954737.268901991]: Shutdown request received.
[ WARN] [1473954737.268978735]: Reason given for shutdown: [user request]
killed
$
```

Only after killing the program does the output suddenly appear. What is happening here? I'm so confused.

Comment: You don't want that `ignore` at all... `clear` is pointless at the beginning, too.

Comment: use cin.sync() it's enough

Comment: Thanks for your input! I only added those because that was the only advice I could find on similar problems, hoping it might help. I've tried cin.sync(), but unfortunately it doesn't change anything either.

Comment: What happens if you comment out the clear and ignore lines? Cin ignores trailing newlines.

Comment: That's what I had at first. I commented out everything and just left `std::cout << "hello "; if(!(std::cin >> input_string)){cout << "this did not work ";} std::cout << "input: " << input_string;` and I get `hello this did not work input:`. (Without ever having had time to input anything.)

Comment: In "the rest of the code" there are several functions calls **before** the attempted input. Something in one of those functions is messing up the input stream.

Comment: It should only be the ROS initialization. All of that is pretty standard. (Not sure if or how much you know about ROS - robot operating system - it's basically a set of libraries that help with building robot applications, it's nothing that we coded or changed at all. I don't really know how these work internally, I assume it shouldn't mess with cin though. But it does seem like that's the only explanation from what I can see...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, turns out I was just being dumb! It wasn't anything to do with the code at all:

I was running everything via a bash script, and because of how I was using it before (which also didn't require any input) I was still running it with **&** at the end - so obviously I couldn't get any input from that shell.

[Note: I wasn't sure if it was good practice to answer one's own question; at first I just edited it. But I figured it'd make more sense than to just leave it open.]

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand your original question about skipping a line but the reason nothing is printed until you shutdown is that you are missing the `endl` from the output. I added it and the output seems as you would expect?

```
char input_test;
std::cout << "character: ";
std::cin >> input_test;
std::cout << input_test;
std::cout << "did that work?" << std::endl;
```

Output:

```
root@93043381199d:/catkin_ws/devel/lib/stack# ./stack_node 
character: a
adid that work?
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your help! Originally the problem was that I didn't get the chance to input anything, it would immediately skip to the next line in the code. Later, the problem was that I did have time to input something, but it would be interpreted as a terminal command, telling me "Befehl nicht gefunden" = "Command not found". However, I did end up being able to solve it - it wasn't a problem with the code after all, it was because of the bash script I used to start it... I was simply being very stupid.